# Windows 7 switch from Python 2.7.5 to 2.7.2

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7

I have multiple machines that I test my program on. One is running Python 2.7.5 and exhibiting a bug that another is not which is running Python 2.7.2. I'd like to change the machine running Python 2.7.5 to 2.7.2.

So I went to: http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.2/

And I downloaded: `Windows x86 MSI Installer (2.7.2)`

I ran it and told it to overwrite my existing install. Finished the install. Started up a console and typed in `python` and it printed out:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

So it obviously didn't work. I restarted my computer then typed in `python` again. Same output. I ran the installer again and instead chose to uninstall. I typed `python` into the shell and it said it wasn't recognized. So far so good. I ran the installer again and installed for all users (same as I always do.) Typed in `python` and it spat out the same message as above.

What the heck!? How do I get python version 2.7.2!?

Is it maybe a problem with the download server? Has someone mistakenly overwritten the 2.7.2 file with a 2.7.5 file?

Comment: If you found a bug, you should report it at http://bugs.python.org/

Comment: Why would you need to do this? All 2.7.x versions are compatible.

Comment: Why not remove the old installation, then do a clean install, rather than counting on the installer's upgrade code to handle downgrading properly?

Comment: @Blender well, there could be a regression (although Python's test suite is extensive, it's hardly perfect), or, probably more likely, the code was relying on some behavior that was implementation dependent and was fixed.

Comment: @Blender: It's not inconceivable there could be a new bug in 2.7.5—or, more likely, that there could be a bug in the OP's code that he got away with in 2.7.2 but that has been exposed by changes in 2.7.5. (For example, there's lots of code that depends on `HTMLParser` not raising exceptions in some places where it should, some of which were fixed in 2.7.3.)

Comment: @abarnert - as detailed in my answer, I attempted this already.

Comment: @Blender - I'm eliminating variables so I can hunt down the bug. I need to know if the issue is the fact that my different computers have different versions of Python or if the issue is with some other variable I've not yet thought of.

Comment: @JBernardo - Absolutely, I will if I find the issue pertains to 2.7.5. Also, whoever downvoted, why? As far as I can tell, this question has never been asked before and I believe I've outlined the issue and my attempts at solving it fairly well... if you see issues with it lacking clarity, why not edit it?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: Where is that detailed in your answer? Are you really positive that running an uninstaller on a broken, half-and-half installation will clean everything up? I'm not. And just checking that `python.exe` is no longer on the path doesn't verify that. Just look at the directory (C:\Python, or whatever else you called it) to see if it's there. And if it is, trash it. Trying to guess what's going on at two removes from the filesystem is fine when everything is working, but when you know things are broken, you can't debug things that way.

Comment: @abarnert - I completely deleted Python and ran the installer again. It said it was going to install Python 2.7.2. I ended up with Python 2.7.5, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer.
Go into Control Panel > Uninstall a program.
Scroll down to Python and uninstall it.

In my case, I had many versions of Python. I have no idea where any of them were installed - I couldn't get the uninstaller to tell me, and it wasn't anywhere in my path, but somehow it would magically gain the ability to find the other installs every time I installed Python 2.7.2. Using this built in uninstaller to uninstall all the versions and then only reinstall 2.7.2 worked.